# What evaluates to false in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

`false` and `nil` evaluate to **false** in `Ruby`. Anything else? Please provide links to official/authoritative references.

```
2.0.0p247 :001 > if true ; puts 'TRUE' ; else puts 'FALSE' ; end
TRUE

2.0.0p247 :002 > if false ; puts 'TRUE' ; else puts 'FALSE' ; end
FALSE

2.0.0p247 :003 > if nil ; puts 'TRUE' ; else puts 'FALSE' ; end
FALSE

2.0.0p247 :004 > if 0 ; puts 'TRUE' ; else puts 'FALSE' ; end
TRUE

2.0.0p247 :005 > if [] ; puts 'TRUE' ; else puts 'FALSE' ; end
TRUE

2.0.0p247 :006 > if {} ; puts 'TRUE' ; else puts 'FALSE' ; end
TRUE

2.0.0p247 :007 > if '' ; puts 'TRUE' ; else puts 'FALSE' ; end
(irb):616: warning: string literal in condition
TRUE
```

Comment: By the way: you're code example can be expressed much shorter
`[true, false, nil, 0, [], {}, ''].map {|o| !!o }`
`#=> [true, false, false, true, true, true, true]`

Comment: Sorry for the downvote. Errant click last week and I can't change it now!

Comment: @JohnMadhavan-Reese - no problem, and thanks for letting me know :)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`false` and `nil` are the only ones:

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/FalseClass.html

Rails provides `present?` which also includes empty strings and empty arrays:  http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-present-3F

Comment: "false and nil are the only ones"

Unless you have a custom class that defines `!@`, which can return `true`, `false`, `"foobar"`, whatever.

Answer (score 9):

You just found them all

> In Ruby, false and nil are “falsy”, while all other values are “truthy”

as Yehuda Katz mentioned in his [blog post in 2009](http://yehudakatz.com/2009/10/04/emulating-smalltalks-conditionals-in-ruby/)

Answer (score 2):

The only `false`-y values in Ruby are `false` and `nil`, as attested to by the book "The Ruby Programming Language", by David Flanagan and Yukihiro Matsumoto (*the* Matz):

> Predicates typically return one of the Boolean values `true` or `false`, but this is not required, as **any value other than `false` or `nil` works like `true` when a Boolean value is required**. (The `Numeric` method `nonzero?`, for example, returns `nil` if the number it is invoked on is zero, and just returns the number otherwise.)

(emphasis mine)

This quote can be found on [page 180](http://books.google.com/books?id=rbY5mz-_VdQC&pg=PA180&lpg=PA180#v=onepage&q&f=false) of the book.

Answer (score 1):

I can only agree, that `nil` and `false` are indeed the only two values, that evaluate to **false** in Ruby. I just wanted to point to another useful resource:

[True and False vs. "Truthy" and "Falsey" (or "Falsy") in Ruby, Python, and JavaScript](https://gist.github.com/jfarmer/2647362)

Answer (score 0):

Note that even though `false` and `nil` are the only objects that result in *false* in a Boolean context, that's when tested **directly** in a Boolean context, e.g., the object in question corresponds to the expression being tested in an `if`.

In particular, an object can still customize the logical *not* operator. That is, how the unary `!` operator and the keyword `not` behave, and this can lead to surprises.

```
class FakeFalsy
    def !
        true
    end
end
```

`FakeFalsy` above defines a `!` method customizing this way the behaving of the logical not. Note that an instance of `FakeFalsy` isn't either `false` or `nil`:

```
>> obj = FakeFalsy.new
...
>> obj.equal? false
=> false
>> obj.equal? nil
=> false
```

Yet it may still look that the object being tested is either `false` or `nil`:

```
>> puts "It seems to be false or nil" if !obj
It seems to be false or nil
=> nil
puts "It seems to be false or nil" if not obj
It seems to be false or nil
=> nil
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to `nil` and `false` evaluating falsey in Ruby, undefined *global* and *instance* variables also evaluate as falsey.

```
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> @x = 3
=> 3
irb(main):002:0> puts "defined" if @x
defined
=> nil
irb(main):003:0> puts "defined" if @y
=> nil
irb(main):004:0> puts "defined" if $y
=> nil
```

Local variables do not work this way:

```
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> puts "defined" if y
(irb):1:in `<main>': undefined local variable or method `y' for main:Object (NameError)
        from /home/mslinn/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/irb-1.7.4/exe/irb:9:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/mslinn/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/bin/irb:25:in `load'
        from /home/mslinn/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/bin/irb:25:in `<main>'
```

I have never found documentation for this behavior, but Ruby has always worked this way.

Code is truth. Documentation can be falsey.

Comment: It's also `nil`, try `@y.nil?`

Comment: Docs said: [an uninitialized instance variable has a value of `nil`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Instance+Variables) and [an uninitialized global variable has a value of `nil`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Global+Variables). That's why this answer does not introduce anything new. `nil` and `false` are falsey, others are truthy