# rails 4 radio_button_tag default not selected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, radio-button, slim-lang

I'm using Rails 4 but I can't get the radio_button_tag to set the first option as default.

```
.field
  =radio_button_tag :type, "order", checked:"true", class: "rfi_radio"
  =label_tag :type_order, "Information pertaining to an order"
  br
  =radio_button_tag :type, "quote", class: "rfi_radio"
  =label_tag :type_quote, "Information pertaining to a quote"
  br
  =radio_button_tag :type, "customer", class: "rfi_radio"
  =label_tag :type_customer, "Information pertaining to a customer"
  br
  =radio_button_tag :type, "general", class: "rfi_radio"
  =label_tag :type_general, "General information"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails was setting the default radio buttons as checked by default.  I had to set all the alternates as false before it would work correctly.

```
.field
  =radio_button_tag "type", "order", true,  class: "rfi_radio"
  =label_tag :type_order, "Information pertaining to an order"
  br
  =radio_button_tag "type", "quote", false, class: "rfi_radio"
  =label_tag :type_quote, "Information pertaining to a quote"
  br
  =radio_button_tag "type", "customer", false, class: "rfi_radio"
  =label_tag :type_customer, "Information pertaining to a customer"
  br
  =radio_button_tag "type", "general", false, class: "rfi_radio"
  =label_tag :type_general, "General information"
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [doc for the `radio_button_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-radio_button_tag).

This should work:

```
.field
    =radio_button_tag :type, "order", true, class: "rfi_radio"
```

Answer (score 1):

According to http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/radio_button_tag, you should just pass in the boolean value and not a hash.

```
=radio_button_tag :type, "order", true, class: "rfi_radio"
```

Comment: I changed the line to  =radio_button_tag :rfi_type, "order", true, class: "rfi_radio" but it didn't change anything.

Comment: What is the HTML generated by the tag?

Comment: <input type="radio" name="rfi_type" id="rfi_type_order" value="order" class="rfi_radio" checked="checked">

Comment: It's a little bit late but maybe recheck all your radio buttons name. There could be another radio button with the same name and have the attribute `checked` too. In that case the last one wins and you will see your first radio button being unchecked even though its HTML does have `checked` inside.

Answer (score 0):

I just spent an hour figuring this out, so want to share in case it helps anyone else:

- The [`radio_button_tag`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.0.3/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-radio_button_tag)'s `checked` parameter will show the radio button as checked no matter what it's provided as the argument (unless `nil` or `false`) since most everything else [is "truthy"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23068894/5783745).
- I had to provide `checked` parameter to ***exactly one*** of the radio buttons in a group (group being those radio buttons with the same name).

Hope these tips help!