# Accessing values in nested hash

Tags: ruby, hash

I'm trying to filter nested hashes and pull various keys and values.  Here is the hash I'm looking at:

```
exp = {
  fam: {cty: "bk", ins: 3},
  spec: {cty: "man", ins: 2},
  br: {cty: "qns", ins: 1},
  aha: {cty: "man", ins: 0}
}
```

I'm trying to find all the hash keys where `cty` is `"man"`.  I'd like to run something where the result is the following hash:

```
e = {
spec: {cty: "man", ins: 2}, 
aha: {cty: "man", ins: 0}
}
```

I tried this and it seems like it almost works:

```
exp.each do |e, c, value|
  c = :cty.to_s
  value = "man"
  if e[c] == value
    puts e
  end
end
```

But the result I get is:

```
=> true
```

Instead of what I'm looking for:

```
e = {
spec: {cty: "man", ins: 2}, 
aha: {cty: "man", ins: 0} 
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. We don't care what your experience level is, just show us your research and that you've put good effort into solving the problem, then write a good question. Please don't use salutations, valedictions or signatures; SO isn't a discussion forum, it's a reference book of questions and answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start, you need to understand what iterating over a hash will give you.

Consider this:

```
exp = {
  fam: {cty: "bk", ins: 3},
  spec: {cty: "man", ins: 2},
  br: {cty: "qns", ins: 1},
  aha: {cty: "man", ins: 0}
}
exp.map { |e, c, value| [e, c, value] }
# => [[:fam, {:cty=>"bk", :ins=>3}, nil], [:spec, {:cty=>"man", :ins=>2}, nil], [:br, {:cty=>"qns", :ins=>1}, nil], [:aha, {:cty=>"man", :ins=>0}, nil]]
```

This is basically what you're doing as you loop and Ruby passes the block the key/value pairs. You're telling Ruby to give you the current hash key in `e`, the current hash value in `c` and, since there's nothing else being passed in, the `value` parameter becomes `nil`.

Instead, you need a block variable for the key, one for the value:

```
    exp.map { |k, v| [k, v] }
# => [[:fam, {:cty=>"bk", :ins=>3}], [:spec, {:cty=>"man", :ins=>2}], [:br, {:cty=>"qns", :ins=>1}], [:aha, {:cty=>"man", :ins=>0}]]
```

Notice that the nil values are gone.

Rewriting your code taking that into account, plus refactoring it for simplicity:

```
exp = {
  fam:  {cty: 'bk',  ins: 3},
  spec: {cty: 'man', ins: 2},
  br:   {cty: 'qns', ins: 1},
  aha:  {cty: 'man', ins: 0}
}

exp.each do |k, v|
  if v[:cty] == 'man'
    puts k
  end
end

# >> spec
# >> aha
```

Now it's returning the keys you want, so it becomes easy to grab the entire hashes. [`select`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-select) is the appropriate method to use when you're trying to locate specific things:

```
exp = {
  fam:  {cty: 'bk',  ins: 3},
  spec: {cty: 'man', ins: 2},
  br:   {cty: 'qns', ins: 1},
  aha:  {cty: 'man', ins: 0}
}

e = exp.select { |k, v| v[:cty] == 'man' }
# => {:spec=>{:cty=>"man", :ins=>2}, :aha=>{:cty=>"man", :ins=>0}}
```

Older versions of Ruby didn't maintain hash output from the hash iterators so we'd have to coerce back to a hash:

```
e = exp.select { |k, v| v[:cty] == 'man' }.to_h
# => {:spec=>{:cty=>"man", :ins=>2}, :aha=>{:cty=>"man", :ins=>0}}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
e = {}
exp.each do |k,v|
  if v[:cty] == "man"
    e[k] = v
  end
end

p e
```

or even

```
e = exp.select do |k,v|
  v[:cty] == "man"  
end
```

Answer (score 0):

As the Tin Man pointed out, there are two parameters you can pass in to a block (the code between `do` and `end` in this case) when iterating through a hash --- one for its key and the other for its value.
To iterate though a hash (and print out its values)

```
h = { a: "hello", b: "bonjour", c: "hola" }
```

using `.each` method, you can do:

```
h.each do |key, value|
  puts  value
end
```

The result will be:

```
hello
bonjour
hola
 => {:a=>"hello", :b=>"bonjour", :c=>"hola"}
```

Please note that the value "returned" is the hash we iterated through, which evaluates to `true` in ruby. (Anything other than `nil` or `false` will evaluate to `true` in Ruby. See [What evaluates to false in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23068834/what-evaluates-to-false-in-ruby))

This is important because the reason you got `true` in your code (which in fact should be `{:fam=>{:cty=>"bk", :ins=>3}, :spec=>{:cty=>"man", :ins=>2}, :br=>{:cty=>"qns", :ins=>1}, :aha=>{:cty=>"man", :ins=>0}}`), rather than the parsed hash you wanted is that the value returned by `.each` method for a hash is the hash itself (which evaluates to `true`).

Which is why osman created an empty hash `e = {}` so that, during each iteration of the hash, we can populate the newly created hash `e` with the key and value we want.

This explains why he can do:

```
e = exp.select do |k,v|
  v[:cty] == "man"  
end
```

Here the code depends upon `select` method being able to return a new hash with the key and value we want (rather than the original hash as is the case for `.each` method).

But if you do

```
e = exp.each do |k,v|
  v[:cty] == "man"  
end
```

The variable `e` will be assigned the original hash `exp` itself, which is not what we want. Therefore it's very important to understand what the returned value is when applying a method.

For more information about return values (and Ruby in general), I highly recommend the free e-book from LaunchSchool "Introduction to Programming with Ruby" (https://launchschool.com/books/ruby). This not only helped me recognise the importance of return values, but also gave me a solid foundation on Ruby prigramming in general, which is really useful if you are planning to learn Ruby on Rails (which I'm doing now :)).

Answer (score 0):

*Simplest way to digging into Nested hash is*:-

```
class Hash
  def deep_find(key, object=self, found=nil)
      if object.respond_to?(:key?) && object.key?(key)
         return object[key]
      elsif object.is_a? Enumerable
         object.find { |*a| found = deep_find(key, a.last) }
         return found
      end
  end
end

Hash.deep_find(key)
```

Comment: Ruby 2.3 added a method [`Hash#dig`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-dig) that makes exactly the same thing.