# Counting symbols in arrays

Tags: arrays, ruby, counting

I have:

```
array1 = [:blue, :blue, :blue, :blue]
array2 = [:green, :green, :yellow, :red]
```

I am trying to count how many blue symbols are in `array2`, which is `0`. I did:

```
near_matches = 0
array1.each do |color1|
  if array2.count(color1)
    near_matches += 1
  end
end

near_matches #=> 4
```

There are no matching color symbols in `array1` with `array2`, and yet I still get `4` as an output. I was wondering why the output of my code is `4`.

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're trying to do here. 1. Is there a reason you append `each` with `with_index`? You don't use the index anywhere in your code. 2. Iterating over `array1` seems pointless since they all contain the same object, maybe this is a test array? Either way `array1.uniq` maybe the better choice to stop repeating yourself. 3. Why are you measuring the count if you're not using it anywhere?

Comment: *"I am trying to count how many blue symbols are in array2"*. `array2.count(:blue) #=> 0` will do the trick.

Comment: You need to explain what you are trying to do, in words, at the beginning. For example, "Given two arrays, `array1` and `array2`, and an object, `obj`, return the number of times `obj` appears in `array1`, provided `obj` appears at least once in `array2`. If `obj` does not appear in `array2`, return `0`". Note that the solution is the same regardless of the classes to which the objects belong.

Comment: You are "trying to count how many blue symbols are in `array2`". Not sure how `array1` has any relevance here, and why you have `array1` in your code.

Answer (score 3):

`count` method returns a number, and every number is truthy in Ruby. The only non-truthy values are `nil` and `false`, so this expression

```
near_matches += 1
```

is always performed. Maybe you could do

```
if array2.count(color1) > 0
  near_matches += 1
end
```

Comment: `unless array2.count(color1).zero?` looks better

Comment: Debatable, I'd say :)

Comment: @Ilya preceded by `near_matches += 1`?

Comment: `near_matches += 1 if array2.include?(color1)` may be more efficient than `count` as the former terminates as soon as one instance of `color1` is found. Both `include?` and `count` are written in C. `include?` arguably reads better as well, as it's not really the `count` that is wanted. In that regard `any?` would be even better, but it requires a block.

Comment: I'm not sure this is correct. What should happen if `:blue` appears twice in `array2`? Why not simply use `near_matches += array2.count(color1)`?

Comment: I'm not sure too because the question is totally unclear to me. I just wanted to point out the issue. Don't mind about the algorithm the user wants to implement.

Answer (score 1):

`nil` and `false` are the only two values, that evaluate to `false` in Ruby.

ref: [What evaluates to false in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23068834/what-evaluates-to-false-in-ruby)

`array2.count(color1)` will never return `nil` or `false` so near_matches always incremented and at the end its value is equal to `array1.size`

you should use inject

```
array1.uniq.inject(0){ |sum,color| sum + array2.count(color) }
```

Comment: @sagar Pandya Thanks for formatting.
I am new to StackOverflow. next time I format the content before posting.
Thanks!

Comment: @CarySwoveland sry for the late reply.
I mean other than `false and nil`  all values are logically evaluated to `true` 
ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23068834/what-evaluates-to-false-in-ruby

let me know if you have any different thoughts on that 
thanks!

Comment: sry for the confusion have updated it.
Thanks and Have a great day ahead!