# How do I access "selected", "focused", "enabled" properties on Android using Ruby/Appium?

Tags: appium, appium-android

I am trying to access those properties in the following way:

```
def check_if_element_is_selected element
  if element.selected?
    return true
  else
    fail "The element is not selected"
  end
end
```

But I keep getting the following error:

```
undefined method `selected?' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Is there any other way to check these properties?

Comment: Have you tried `element.attribute('checked')`?

Comment: I don't know anything about Appium, but this can be caught by checking if `element` is [truthy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23068834/3784008): `element && element.selected? ? (true) : (false)`

Comment: The `element` is `nil`. You can't get an android property on it because it is not an android object.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look on the [`Appium - Attribute documentation`](http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/element/attributes/attribute/) you can see that you can use the `attribute` function to get the attribute of your element.

In `Ruby` it should be like this:

> ruby_lib example
>
> find_element(:accessibility_id, 'SomeAccessibilityID').attribute("content-desc")

Also you can take a look on [`appium/ruby_lib`](https://github.com/appium/ruby_lib/blob/ad8bf400711005f32440618b370ee2551f172a7d/docs/docs.md) where you can see that you can use

> e.attribute('checked') # is the checkbox checked?

Comment: I tried using e.attribute('checked') but I keep getting the same error **undefined method `attribute' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)** // I'm using ruby 2.3.7p456 (2018-03-28 revision 63024) [universal.x86_64-darwin17]