# Simplify Assignment in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I just want to assign the value of variable `B` to variable `A` only if `B` is not `nil`.
And I want to simplify the code as possible.
So I found the one.

```
A = B if B
```

But variable name is long such as `data[:Symbol1][:Symbol2]...` , anyhow same variable name is duplicated.

Can anybody help me with simplifying this code?

Comment: Not completely clear the part of the duplicated name, can you make an example. Try `a = b || a`.

Answer (score 1):

You might try the [`presence`](https://apidock.com/rails/Object/presence) method.

Your code would look like

```
A = B.presence
```

Example of it in action:

```
[1] pry(main)> b = nil
=> nil
[2] pry(main)> a = b.presence
=> nil
[3] pry(main)> a
=> nil
[4] pry(main)> b = 'foo'
=> "foo"
[5] pry(main)> a = b.presence
=> "foo"
[6] pry(main)> a
=> "foo"
```

Comment: If `a = :something` you turn a into `nil`. So this is just `a = b`?

Comment: In which version of ruby, does it work?
b.presence gives error presence undefined in nil:NilClass.

Comment: @Romeo, `require 'rails'` or `require 'active_support/core_ext/object'`.

Comment: @Romeo your title said you were using Ruby on Rails so I gave a Rails specific solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you need `A = B || A`.

The `||` operator evaluates **and returns** the first non-false operand. If B is "[truthy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23068834/what-evaluates-to-false-in-ruby)", it will return B (and assign it to A). If B is false, A will just be assigned itself.

Answer (score 0):

2 simple ways:

```rb
a = b.presence || a
```

Or

```rb
a = b || a
```